# How to change the screen orientation (Tizen, Web-app)

Tags: web-applications, tizen, tizen-web-app

I can set screen orientation on config.xml screen-orientation="portrait" or "landscape".
This setting for all pages.

How i can change screen orientation from code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

screen.lockOrientation("portrait");

screen.lockOrientation("landscape");

[developer.tizen.org/help/index.jsp](https://developer.tizen.org/help/index.jsp?topic=/org.tizen.web.w3c.apireference/w3c_api.html)

Answer (score 0):

screen.lockOrientation(...) and screen.unlockOrientation(...) may be used from code. See discussion here: https://developer.tizen.org/forums/web-application-development/automatic-orientation-tizen-web-application